# Not all CPUs entered broadcast exception handler Kernel Error

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, cpu

I've been dual booting Ubuntu on my laptop and for a few months its been perfect. Today however when booting up this error has appeared, and despite numerous restarts nothing has resolved it:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing:  Timeout: Not all CPUs entered broadcast exception handler
Kernel Offset: disabled
Rebooting in 30 seconds.
```

When booting into Windows 10 I have no problems or issues, so I dont think its a hardware issue, maybe an update that has prevented an Ubuntu boot.

I've looked around for solutions but most say it's a hardware issue (which I doubt) or I need to update the Intel Microcode, however if I can't load into Ubuntu and install it how can I possibly update the microcode?

Answer (score 1):

If your CPU is an Intel Braswell (like mine is, namely in my case a N3050) then you might be able to solve the issue by booting the kernel with option :

```
max_cstate=1
```

Or, alternatively, set maximum Cstate to C1 in your BIOS/UEFI.

It worked for me. I had the same sort of issue.

If it's a low consumption and low TDP CPU like the N3050, that shouldn't be much of an issue, compared to not having any linux kernel booting ^^

Ref :

[bugzilla](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051)

Comment: when in the boot mode add that 'max_cstate=1' parameter after word of 'quite' am i right? @BTH